# Op amp only getting half wave output on dual power supply

Tags: operational-amplifier, h-bridge

In my project I'm putting together a H bridge circuit which uses the N Channel type MOSFETS only and it is controlled by my amplified Arduino square wave signal that is operating the MOSFET Gates which is connected to the outputs of my dual op amp setup (the op amp IC I'm using is the LM1458). The first op amp is the inverting op amp circuit and the second op amp is non-inverted.

So far the build is nearly all complete and both the non-inverted and inverted output signals are amplifying the Arduino PWM square wave signal the way I want however I'm only getting getting a half wave signal from both outputs and as a result only Q1 and Q4 are turning on and off as those N channel MOSFETS are receiving the positive signal while Q2 and Q3 are only receiving the negative signal which results them being switched off all the time. I definitely know there is a fault in regards to how I've setup the dual supply for the op amps as for some reason it is behaving like it is a single supply. And my code in the Arduino is definitely making a full square wave signal too. I've already tested with my oscilloscope on both outputs from the op amps and both of them have half wave signals so the fault I believe is the dual Supply for the op amps, just that I'm a bit confused as to why my dual power supply is not powering the other cycle and how to fix it.

The reason why I'm posting this is because I find there isn't much clear information out there in regards to setting up a dual power supply properly on a dual op amp setup and it is probably something small I've overlooked when building this circuit. I've also already did this same circuit in a simulator and it worked (but as we all know simulators are not always completely accurate).

[image]

Comment: (1) You could greatly improve schematic legibility by placing GND symbols at each grounded component pin and eliminate all the ground networks. Remove unnecessary kinks in the networks. (2) PWM10 has a direct short-circuit to GND. (3) You have no component designations (C1, Q1, etc.) so it's going to be difficult to discuss your schematic. (4) The 47000 uF cap seems to have a short-circuit (blue line). Lay it out again maximising readability.

Comment: You say you're using a LM1458 dual opamp, but your pin numbering shows 2 individual single (741-style) opamps. You also have the supply pins reversed.

Comment: Power supply voltages are needed  To be stated and, don’t wait until tomorrow, if you want my advice. Likely is that you are not driving the upper MOSFETs at all with what I see.

Answer (score 2):

This is already said by others, but to be conductive your N-mosfets (see NOTE1) need gate voltage which is few volts above what's at the cathode. The upper mosfets get only what's available from the opamp power supply minus about 1V drop in the opamp. This can work only if your bridge supply voltage is several volts lower than the +supply voltage for opamps. Q2 and Q4 could be driven properly if the frequency is usable for opamps and the mosfets do not get fried due too high Vgs.

Find some proven circuits. It's useless to replace a wheel with a rectangle. Driving gates generally need more complex solutions than yours. Having only N-mosfets make things twice complex. You must use boostrapping or some other method to rise the voltage above the bridge supply voltage. The most popular solution is to have P-mosfets as the upper halves and drive them with a transistor which can accept the control signal against GND like this:

[image]

Search for mosfet H-bridge for Arduino!

NOTE1: The arrow in your mosfet symbol is taken from the symbol of a P-channel device. I think you have still intended these to be N-channel mosfets.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation and advice on what I'm not doing right and it all makes perfect sense now after reading your advice a few times. I'm going to make some changes once I get back to my work space over the next couple of days and will post the results on how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

The proper implantation of Nch only bridges is to use low side PWM for a charge pump, so that edges are used to rectify Vboost greater than Vdd for high side direction control FETs.

The other implementation uses complimentary Pch + Nch FETs where Nch have a cost/performance advantage and both require deadtime control, but is more critical in complementary FETs to prevent shootthru.